# Making Pickles - Confirming Sanitization Procedure

Tags: food-preservation, canning, pickling

I'm about to make a batch of dill pickles. The recipe it pretty straightforward:

- A batch of firm baby cucumbers
- 1 cup of water
- 1 cup of vinegar
- 1 heaping tablespoon of salt
- 4 cloves of garlic, sliced
- 1 pinch of red pepper flakes

The instructions are also pretty straightforward. Sterilize the canning equipment (jars, lids, seals) in boiling water for at least five minutes. Add the washed cucumbers to the jars, boil the water, vinegar, and everything else, and add it to the jar as well. Seal the jars, and then process them in a large pot of boiling water for five minutes. All to cool over 24 hours, and they're good for a year.

Does this sound about right? I don't want them to spoil.

Thank you in advance!

**References**

---

1. *How to Make Pickles*, Accessed 2014-04-02, [`<http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-dill-pickles-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-193350>`](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-dill-pickles-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-193350)

Comment: 5 minutes is a short processing time, especially for cold-pack. I hope these are very small jars. Pay close attention to be sure all the lids "pop" down after removing from the canner.

Comment: @KateGregory Do you have a better recipe or source I could use? If this sounds off, I'd like to use a recipe with an established name behind it. Even with the brine solution being pre-boiled, five minutes processing time still isn't enough?

Comment: See http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/general/selecting_correct_process_time.html which suggests a lot longer for raw pack. Since you have a vinegar brine (ie you're not canning tomatoes or peaches) you might argue that as long as your lids pop, you're good. It's your decision but 5 minutes seems a really short process. I process pints of pickles for 10 minutes myself, room temp veggies hot brine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* reasonable:  the large quantity of vinegar will acidify the pickles, preventing the growth of botulism.

The processing step is mostly to seal the jars; the vinegar is the real preservation agent.

Still, I would feel better if The Kitchn had cited the source of the recipe, as you only want to use recipes that come from a trusted and qualified source.